# Problem with voltage to current converter

Tags: operational-amplifier

[image]

[image]

I want to get 20 mA output (current) when input is 3.3 V and 0 mA when the input is 0 V.

I have tested my circuit but I got about 11 mA when input is 0 V and about 12 mA when input is 3.3 V.

Comment: It would be a lot easier to see what was going on if you drew the individual amplifiers on the schematic.

Comment: Go step by step and check the output of the first opamp and check if you are getting the same voltage as the input voltage. Then, check the second opamp output. If one of these voltages is incorrect, check the positive and negative terminals of that opamp and see if they are equal.

Answer (score 0):

Note that neither opamp's output stage functions linearly all the way down to 0.00 V.  To achieve the condition of 0.0 V in = 0.0 mA out, you will need a negative supply rail for both opamps.

This should help:

https://www.ti.com/lit/an/snoa474a/snoa474a.pdf

Answer (score 0):

At Vin=3.3V condition, the output voltage of the second opamp will be 20.625V assuming ideal opamp. This means that VCC of 15V is not sufficient because the output cannot be higher than the supply. At VCC of 15V, maximum output is probably saturating at ~11V which is why you are reading less than 20mA.

At Vin=0V, the output of the first opamp is probably not 0V but saturating at ~2V which may be the reason for reading more than 0mA.

Adjusting VEE lower and increasing VCC is something you should try.